# TS2322: Type 'Redis' is not assignable to type 'RedisClient'. issue on Docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, redis, node-redis

I try to build an node.js app but I have an error like ;

```
 => ERROR [build 7/7] RUN npx nx build driver-api --prod                                                                                                                           53.9s 
------                                                                                                                                                                                   
 > [build 7/7] RUN npx nx build driver-api --prod:                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                
nx run driver-api:build:production                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                               
chunk (runtime: main) main.js (main) 348 KiB [entry] [rendered]                                                                                                                

ERROR in /app/libs/database/src/lib/redis-pub-sub.provider.ts
./libs/database/src/lib/redis-pub-sub.provider.ts 16:10-19
[tsl] ERROR in /app/libs/database/src/lib/redis-pub-sub.provider.ts(16,11)
TS2322: Type 'Redis' is not assignable to type 'RedisClient'.
Type 'Redis' is missing the following properties from type 'Redis': stream, isCluster, connector, reconnectTimeout, and 140 more.

ERROR in /app/libs/database/src/lib/redis-pub-sub.provider.ts
./libs/database/src/lib/redis-pub-sub.provider.ts 17:10-20
[tsl] ERROR in /app/libs/database/src/lib/redis-pub-sub.provider.ts(17,11)
TS2322: Type 'Redis' is not assignable to type 'RedisClient'.

ERROR in libs/database/src/lib/redis-pub-sub.provider.ts:16:11
TS2322: Type 'Redis' is not assignable to type 'RedisClient'.
Type 'Redis' is missing the following properties from type 'Redis': stream, isCluster, connector, reconnectTimeout, and 140 more.
#12 53.66     14 |         };
#12 53.66     15 |         return new RedisPubSub({
#12 53.66   > 16 |           publisher: new Redis(options),
#12 53.66        |           ^^^^^^^^^
#12 53.66     17 |           subscriber: new Redis(options),
#12 53.66     18 |         })
#12 53.66     19 |       } ,
#12 53.66 
#12 53.66 ERROR in libs/database/src/lib/redis-pub-sub.provider.ts:17:11
#12 53.66 TS2322: Type 'Redis' is not assignable to type 'RedisClient'.
#12 53.66     15 |         return new RedisPubSub({
#12 53.66     16 |           publisher: new Redis(options),
#12 53.66   > 17 |           subscriber: new Redis(options),
#12 53.66        |           ^^^^^^^^^^
#12 53.66     18 |         })
#12 53.66     19 |       } ,
#12 53.66     20 |     };
#12 53.66 
#12 53.66 webpack compiled with 4 errors (b984ccb820b8363c)
```

my redis-pub-sub.provider.ts file like ;

```
import { pubSubToken } from '@nestjs-query/query-graphql';
import { RedisPubSub } from 'graphql-redis-subscriptions';
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import { Provider } from '@nestjs/common';

export class RedisPubSubProvider {
  static provider(): Provider {
    return {
      provide: pubSubToken(),
      useFactory: () => {
        const options = {
          host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || 'localhost',
          port: 6379
        };
        return new RedisPubSub({
          publisher: new Redis(options),
          subscriber: new Redis(options),
        })
      } ,
    };
  }
}
```

how can I solve the issue ? can some one help me ?

when I try to build an node.js app I get an error like "TS2322: Type 'Redis' is not assignable to type 'RedisClient'. issue"

Answer (score 2):

The package graphql-redis-subscription expects the type RedisClient for both publisher and subscriber, which it defines as:

```
type RedisClient = Redis | Cluster;
```

So when you create a new Redis() object, the package does not accept the type Redis and you could theoretically define it as RedisClient by doing

```
new Redis(options) as RedisClient
```

But the package does not export this type as of today, so you cannot do that without modifying the package locally.

I solved it by instead doing

```
new Redis(options) as any
```

Which is not best practice but resolves the build error.
I am going to open a PR to have the type exported.